# Gnu Radio Companion like Interface

Tags: xml, user-interface, gnuradio, freemind

I like how Gnu Radio Companion allows you to select and drag components to the screen and connect them.

Are there any other tools out there that allow you to plug in the blocks, and tell it the formatting to generate when you try to output a file?

UPDATE:

I have been looking at Freemind, and it's similar, but I can't just create blocks to add in, I would have to manually type in pieces, which I don't like very much. (room for error then)